# How to iterate a standard dictionary but in async way

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How to iterate over a standard dictionary but in async way.

For example :

```
import asyncio
import uuid

async def procDict(k,v):
    print('{}-->{}'.format(k,v))

async def main(indict):
    async for k in indict:
        await procDict(k,indict[k])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d=dict()
    for i in range(5):
        d[str(i)]={'uuid':uuid.uuid1().hex}
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(d))
```

That snipet above got a traceback :
'async for' requires an object with **aiter** method, got dict'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sambat.py", line 16, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(d))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "./sambat.py", line 8, in main
    async for k in indict:
TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got dict
```

Comment: There’s no I/O involved in iterating a dictionary, so what would that even entail? What you probably want is something like `await asyncio.gather(*[procDict(k, v) for k, v in indict.items()])`

Comment: @dirn you are right. I really appreciate your help.